# How to render my own class correctly in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, class, jcombobox

I want to fill a JComboBox using a DefaultComboBoxModel.

```
static JComboBox<Carta> cmb_cartas;
static DefaultComboBoxModel<Carta> mdl_cartas;
```

I fill the DefaultComboBoxModel with an ArrayList of my own class "Carta"

```
ArrayList<Carta> cartas = conOAD.getCartasPorAgregar(idConjunto);

mdl_cartas = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Carta>();

for(int i = 0; i < cartas.size(); i++) {
    Carta carta = cartas.get(i);
    mdl_cartas.addElement(carta);
}
cmb_cartas = new JComboBox<>(mdl_cartas);
```

The combobox is filled correctly but the problem is that the text of the options are displaying: "modelos.Carta@3e7e084e"

How can is set the text to be the attribute "nombre" of my class "Carta"?

Comment: And please avoid using hungarian notation. You should name the combobox cartasComboBox and the model cartasModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the `toString` method for your `Carta` class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return this.nombre; // assumes nombre is a string
}
```

However, many people (rightly) frown on abusing the `toString` method for GUI display purposes. You could instead create a custom [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) to render the text you want for each object.

Comment: A more flexible way to approach this is to implement a `ListCellRenderer` and set it to the combo box.  By 'flexible' I mean that it might return the string form of the class in one renderer, but different things in other renderers.

Comment: I'm sorry man but you just said it: override `toString` method for display purposes is not right. This an easy but not correct approach.